# Trying to run a code with argparse on colab but Nothing happens

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, argparse

I was trying to run this project github.com/yunzhusong/AARD on colab. After installing all requirements I tried to run cell like below:
`

```
!python main.py -train_detector -fold 0,1,2,3,4 -dataset_dir dataset/Pheme -savepath results/Pheme -filter True -batch_size 48 -log_tensorboard -warmup_steps 100
```

`

The cell runs without any errors but nothing happens! I think the cell reads main.py without the remaining arguments. How can I solve this issue and run the command with its args?

Comment: what is supposed to happen?

Comment: I mean the training process didn't begin as I it happened in my pc.